# Rails f.submit: how to add html attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I'm having trouble adding a particular `html` attribute to a Rails form submit.

```
= form_for :model do |f|
  ...
  = f.submit 'Submit', tabindex: '3'
```

The `tabindex` property isn't showing up in the form. I also tried a `html` hash to no avail.

It just produces this `html` markup:

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

**EDIT**: The only alternative way I can think of is to use jQuery.

```
$('button[type=submit]').attr('tabindex', '3');
```

But that seems overkill. It seems like there should be a way in Haml.

Comment: Something else is going on here... that should work.  What happens when you add a class to the options also?  `f.submit 'Submit', class: 'some-class', tabindex: '3'`

Comment: And that should be making an `input` element, not a `button` element.  Are you looking at the right view?

Comment: I'm looking at the right view, but it turns out we were overriding it by using a custom form builder. If you add some answer to that effect, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `f.submit 'Submit', tabindex: '3'` should be:

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit' tabindex='3'></input>
```

However, you appear to be getting a `button` element, and the `tabindex` is not showing up at all - so something else is definitely going on here.

If you have a custom form builder and override the `submit` method, this could certainly be the result.  If you need that custom form builder and still want your submit element to be a button you'll need to make sure you're allowing an options hash through the submit method.  Not sure what your current method looks like, but you might update it to something like this:

```
def submit(value, options={})
  options.reverse_merge!(
    type: 'submit',
    value: value
  )

  button_tag(value, options)
end
```